# query list student where grade just b

Tags: mysql

i have some table

table: mhsw
nim; name; prodi
1001; willy; SIF
1002; karel; SIF
1003; fikri; TIF
1004; wawan; DPI

table: krs
mkid; mkname; grade; final
1001; mk1; A; Y
1001; mk2; B; Y
1001; mk3; B; Y
1002; mk2; C; Y
1002; mk3; B; Y
1002; mk1; D; Y
1003; mk1; A; Y
1003; mk2; B; Y
1003; mk3; A; Y
1004; mk1; A; Y
1004; mk2; D; Y
1005; mk3; A; Y

i want my result 
nim; name; prodi
1001; willy; SIF
1003; fikri; TIF

the condition is print mhsw list where all mkid on krs table is all grade A,B,C  and final is Y and not to display when grade is D or E

i need the mysql query
thanks

Answer (score 0):

One optional is to use conditional aggregation on the `krs` table to identify which students had only `A`, `B`, or `C` grades along with all `Y` for the final.

```
SELECT t1.nim,
       t1.name,
       t1.prodi
FROM mhsw t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT mkid
    FROM krs
    GROUP BY mkid
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN grade NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'C') THEN 1 END) = 0 AND   -- only A,B,C
           SUM(CASE WHEN final = 'Y' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)   -- all final is Y
) t2
    ON t1.nim = t2.mkid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mhsw.*,tbl.*
FROM mhsw 
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT mkid
     FROM krs
     Where grade IN ('A', 'B', 'C') 
     AND final = 'Y') tbl ON mhsw.nim = tbl.mkid
```

## If mhsw.nim = tbl.mkid has multiple row, it would display as:

nim; name; prodi; mkid; mkname; grade; final;
1001; willy; SIF; 1001;mk1; A; Y;
1001; willy; SIF; 1001;mk2; B; Y;
1001; willy; SIF; 1001;mk3; B; Y;
.
..
....
1004; wawan; DPI; 1004; mk1; A; Y;

Comment: i just want order or group by mhsw.name where the grade is A,B,C when is not that grade not to display